# How to add a specific level of access to a custom action in viewset in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, authorization

I have a ModelViewSet in Django Rest Framework with all crud functions and set the permissions to IsAuthenticated, but I made a custom action and want it to be public, but I have no clue on how to do that since the documentation only shows how to do that with an @api_view(), here's my ModelViewSet

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """User viewset"""

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserModelSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def signup(self, request):
        """Sign Up users without profile. """
        serializer = UserSignUpSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user = serializer.save()
            data = {
                'user' : user,
            }
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])     
    def login(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Handle logins request. """
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user, token = serializer.save()
        data= {
            'user': user,
            'access_token' : token
        }
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I want to make the login @action public, I hope you guys can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add parameter to action deacrotor for change permission class.

```
    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'], permission_classes=[AllowAny])     
    def login(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Handle logins request. """
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user, token = serializer.save()
        data= {
            'user': user,
            'access_token' : token
        }
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

[Detail in document](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62415675/10871073) not work for `AllowAny`. For any other permissions it works fine.

As a workaround I found:

```
def get_permissions(self):  
    if self.action in ["login", "another_action_name"]:
        return [
            AllowAny(),
        ]
    return super().get_permissions()
```